# Creating web site works in my portfolio

Tags: wordpress, dns, server, portfolio

I would like to work on creating some web sites for my portfolio(I already have one and it's created with wordpress), but I don't know what to do with domain and stuff. Should I purchase a domain and a hosting for each web site I create??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is completely your decision. You can access your sites with temporary URLs if your hosting provider offers. If you want to access each wordpress sites with separate domains like; http://example.com http://example2.com, you will have to register the domains and point them to your hosting providers' server.

Basically, you will get nameservers from them which you can set from your domain control panel (From where you purchase domain).